# Latitude and longitude values conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, convert, xy, australia

I received a backup file and the latitude and longitude in this backup are very big, for example, Latitude: -106994676, Longitude: 488026770.

I have not idea how to convert them into regular latitude/longitude numbers. Any ideas on how to?

My understanding the position measured should be somewhere close to 29.7282° S, 135.5651° E.

Comment: These coordinates are from a projection. Here ara some projections used in Australia: https://epsg.io/?q=Australia%20kind%3APROJCRS. Try to find which one is your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your latitudes and longitudes are expressed in milliarcseconds. Divide them by 3,600,000 to get values in degrees:

- Latitude : -106994676 / 3600000 = -29.7207433°
- Longitude : 488026770 / 3600000 = 135.5629916°

Comment: would you please also let me know what is the unit for the elevation? Lat: -107013582, Long: 488028330, Elev: 24970. thank you!

Comment: I don't know what the units are for the elevation, sorry. What is the expected elevation of the point? It doesn't look like meters, maybe centimetres? (=249.7m)

Comment: I don't know the expected elevation for that point, but it should be around 200m. Thanks for your reply, that's what I was thinking at the beginning, until I saw some negative values,i.e.  -24856.